# How to cancel focus() of Grav build-in CodeMirror editor

Tags: codemirror, grav

I would like to add my custom WYSIWYG-editor with my plugin over Grav build-in editor without removing the last.

I append my editor as a divider with `contenteditable="true"` to `.CodeMirror-lines > div` as the container where is also build-in `.CodeMirror-code` editor divider. And my editor is above as layer (`z-index` is higher).

But when I click the area, the build-in editor is focused and not mine.

I've viewed the codes of both `user/plugins/admin/themes/grav/js/admin.min.js` and `user/plugins/admin/themes/grav/js/vendor.min.js` to find the row(s) which is(are) responsible for such focusing, but I can't.

Could someone help to cancel this focusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to resolve the problem it's enough to append my editor not to `.CodeMirror-lines > div`, but to `.grav-editor-content` divider